# Memory mapped IO - how does IO device know value has changed?

Tags: io, cpu, cpu-architecture, memory-mapping

How does an IO device know that a value in memory pertaining to it has changed in [memory mapped IO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O)?

For example, let's say memory address 0 has been dedicated to hold the background color for a VGA device. How does the VGA device know when we change the value in memory[0]? Is the VGA device constantly polling the memory location? Or does the CPU somehow notify the device when it changes the value (and if so how?)?

An example architecture is MIPS. Given that the [MIPS instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture) does not have `in` or `out` instructions, I don't understand how it could possibly communicate (on change) with the VGA device in the example. Another example is the ARM architecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In memory-mapped I/O, performing a memory read/write to the device's memory region will cause the CPU to perform a transaction with the device to fetch/store that value -- either directly through the CPU's memory bus, or through a secondary bus (such as AHB/APB on ARM systems). This memory transaction directly notifies the device that a value is being changed; no separate notification is necessary.

You're assuming that memory-mapped I/O is mapped by normal RAM. *This is not the case.* Indeed, these devices may behave in ways which are entirely unlike real memory! For instance, a typical UART or SPI device implementation may have a single data register which can be written to to transmit data, or read from to retrieve received data. Similarly, it's not uncommon for interrupt registers to have "clear on read" or "write 1 to clear" semantics.

For what it's worth: in practice, many framebuffer graphics implementations do actually behave as normal memory. What's different is that the memory is stored in a dual-ported RAM (or a time-multiplexed bus), and the video RAMDAC continuously reads through that memory to transmit its contents to an attached display.

Answer (score 3):

A region of the physical address space that is designated as memory-mapped I/O (MMIO) is not mapped to main memory (system memory); it's mapped to I/O registers which are physically part of the I/O device.

To determine how to handle a memory access (read or write), the processor checks first the type of the region to which the target memory address belongs. In any MIPS processor, there are at least two types: Uncached and Cached. MMIO regions are always Uncached. An Uncached memory access request is directly sent to the main memory controller without examining or affecting any of the caches. However, an I/O Uncached memory access request is sent to an I/O controller, and eventually the request will reach the destination I/O device.

Now exactly how the CPU and the I/O device communicate with each other is completely specified by the I/O device itself. So an I/O device would have a specification that discusses how many I/O registers there are and how each of them should be used. An I/O register could be used to hold status flags, control flags, data to be read or written by the CPU, or some combination thereof. Note that since the I/O registers are physically part of the I/O device, then the I/O device can be designed so that it can detect when any of its registers are being read from or written to and take an action accordingly if required.

An I/O device can send an interrupt to the CPU to inform it that some data is available or maybe it wants attention for whatever reason. The CPU can also frequently poll the I/O device by checking some status flag(s) and then take some action accordingly.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1226197/x86-address-space-controller has some high-level description of how modern x86 systems sort out load/store addresses between DRAM and MMIO, and that with an integrated northbridge / memory controller, that logic is right in the CPU, as well as just the uncacheable / write-back / write-through / uncacheable-with-write-combining memory attributes from the TLB entry.

Comment: @PeterCordes Apparently, what's called the "system agent" in Intel processors is called the "system interface" in MIPS Technologies processors. I've read in the MIPS architecture specification document that during address translation using the TLB, the CPU can determine the type of the memory access (Uncached or Cached). I think that when it's Uncached, it'll be sent directly to the system interface which will check whether it's an I/O or memory request. When I was writing this answer, I wasn't sure what the "system agent" is called in MIPS processors and I was too lazy to check.

Comment: It makes sense to use a bit in each TLB entry to remember whether this page is cacheable or not; otherwise you have to look it up later somewhere else.  I would guess that if x86 MTRRs can override the page attribute in the PTE, they're checked by the page walker.  And probably changing the MTRR invalidates TLB entries.  So the TLB is the one-stop shop for cacheable or not.  I wonder if the page-walker on modern x86 puts MMIO vs. DRAM into the TLB entries?  Probably not, that's probably sorted out closer to the memory controller, like you say for MIPS.

Comment: @PeterCordes There are no MTRR registers in MIPS so it makes sense to use a bit in each TLB entry for that purpose. On x86 processors, I think there are dedicated MTRR registers and the types specified by them are not cached in the TLB. Caching them adds area overhead. So I doubt that, unless accessing the TLB is faster than the MTRRs. But both design choices are possible because none of them violate the x86 spec. Memory types specified in MTRRs and page table entries do not override each over; they are merged in some way. Why would the page table walker check them?...

Comment: ...It's not really its responsibility. Making changes to the MTRRs is not coherent with any of the caches and they are also not coherent with the MTRRs of other processors. It's the OS responsibility to do that. Also the BIOS usually sets up the MTTRs, so they rarely change. Also I agree with you that the distinction of MMIO vs. DRAM is probably done after address translation.

Comment: @PeterCordes In x86, MMIO doesn't technically have to be uncacheable. This is in contrast to MIPS (I'm only 90% sure). I'm not able to find where in the Intel manual the merging of memory types is discussed.

Comment: @PeterCordes I randomly selected a page from the manual and found it lol :). It's in Volume 3 Section 11.5.2.2.

Comment: on x86, PAT or the legacy PCD/PWT selection need to be checked per-page for every load or store, including for L1d cache hit loads.  Why *wouldn't* you want that cached in the TLB which you have to check anyway?  Merging in the MTRR setting into a "how to actually treat this page" entry in the TLB once, when the TLB entry is being written at page-walk time, makes even more sense instead of also checking the MTRRs for every single load as well as the PAT stuff.  It's very common to load repeatedly from the same page...  Also, the final state only takes 2 bits, while the full PAT entry is 3.

Comment: Possible evidence it's designed this way:  A `movntdqa` on Intel CPUs knows *right away* if it's operating on weakly-ordered memory (in which case the NT hint applies) or not (in which case it's almost exactly like a normal `movdqa` load + an ALU uop that does nothing).  Intel wouldn't have designed it this way if it wasn't cheap to implement, I think.  `movntdqa` currently has no use-cases outside of reading from USWC regions, so it's not like they needed to care much about the performance on WB regions.  Non-coherent MTRRs make it even easier; don't have to flush TLB on change, I guess.

Comment: And BTW, Linux kernel log messages report that the kernel simplifies the MTRR regions to take fewer entries, and make sure it's covering the right stuff.  Not all BIOSes did a good job with MTRRs, at least historically, I guess.

Comment: Stores that hit in L1d would be a better example.  They need to distinguish WB from WT at least before they commit.  But actually, you can map the same physical RAM with two different pages, so you could find valid L1d tags for a line in a UC page if a cacheable mapping also exists.  So yes, PAT/MTRR do need to be checked within that 4-cycle load/use latency window, so it totally makes sense to keep the 2 bit status for each page in the TLB, checking the MTRRs only when writing the TLB entry.  (Well, really only *need* to be checked before the load retires, but you still need throughput.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm thinking why Intel requires flushing all the caches and the TLBs when changing an MTRR. I think that Intel wants to have the flexibility regarding where to store MTRRs and how to optimize checking their settings. They may want to store MTRRs in main memory in some boot-time allocated area for the processor. Also, as you said, they may want to cache some settings in the TLB or the final memory type. Or may be even have a separate hardware structure optimized for access containing the final memory types. It's beneficial to efficiently determine the memory type before...

Comment: ...sending a memory request to L1and/or TLB (to save energy, for example, or to avoid structural hazards as you said). So, yes it makes sense to cache the final memory type somewhere. By the way, the final memory type still requires 3 bits, not 2, because there are 5 different types (UC, WC, WT, WP, WB). In older versions of the standard, there was an "undefined" type, which may or may not need its own representation.

Comment: @PeterCordes But these are different permissions. WP means that both reads and writes are allowed. However, writes are not performed on caches irrespective of whether it's a hit or a miss. Instead, writes always directly go the memory controller. But reads can be fetched from caches. I quote from the manual "Reads come from cache lines when possible, and read misses cause cache fills.
Writes are propagated to the system bus and cause corresponding cache lines on all processors on the bus to be invalidated. Speculative reads are allowed."

Comment: Ahhh, I wasn't familiar with WP mode, and was just guessing what it did. >.<  That makes more sense; I didn't think it made sense to duplicate the functionality of the per-page `W` bit.  (deleted my previous comment).  Yeah, that's definitely more than 2 bits of state.  Oh well, 1 extra bit per entry is really not much in a relatively small CAM that already has ~30 bits of physical page indexed by ~30 bits of virtual page bits, plus RWX permissions and Accessed / Dirty flags.  Huh, interesting mode. Not quite like making everything an NT store to cacheable memory, because it's like UC, not WC.

Comment: @PeterCordes I pretty sure Intel has done a lot of research on how to check memory types efficiently since this is very critical, but they never published anything. Even in academic research papers, they usually use academic-grade simulators, all of which don't even model memory types (they are abstracted). So I'm 99% sure no one has done something like that in academia.